# Pure Javascript - setInterval (1s), setAttribute

Tags: javascript, animation, global-variables, setinterval

I'd like to change the color of the sqaure (**#myID: width = height = 100px**) every second. *(To check if that switch loop works, in every "case" I wrote **console.log("smth happened");**.)*
But the color of this square does not change. ["FIDDLE"](http://jsfiddle.net/kardaw/M9rtM/1/)

Next thing, every second **document.getElementById('myID')** is written to a new formed variable **thesquare**. How to make the variable global, outside the function?

Javascript:

```
var i = 0;
function changecolor()
{       
    var thesquare = document.getElementById('myID');
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0 :
        thesquare.setAttribute("background-color","red");
        ++i;
        break;

        case 1 :
        thesquare.setAttribute("background-color","green");
        ++i;
        break;

        default :
        thesquare.setAttribute("background-color","blue");
        i=0;
        break;
    }
}
setInterval("changecolor()",1000);
```

Comment: `setInterval(changecolor,1000);`

Comment: How is this "*pure* javascript? It uses the DOM api.

Comment: Pure Javascript - No jQuery

Comment: @Bergi I think you get the idea he is trying to convey. I suppose it means 'without framework' in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an attribute you want to set but a `style`:

```
thesquare.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Your function does work but the attribute `background-color` does not do anything.

Also, `setInterval("changecolor()",1000);` should be `setInterval(changecolor,1000);`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M9rtM/3/)

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti That method uses eval, which should be avoided. putvande's suggestion is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> Next thing, every second document.getElementById('myID') is written to
>   a new formed variable thesquare. How to make the variable global,
>   outside the function?

You don't need to use a global, you can keep it in an outer scope using a closure and an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE):

```
(function() {
  var thesquare = document.getElementById('myID');
  var i = 0;

  function changecolor() {
    switch (i) {
        case 0 :
          thesquare.style.backgroundColor = "red";
          ++i;
          break;

        case 1 :
          thesquare.style.backgrounColor = "green";
          ++i;
          break;

        default :
          thesquare.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
          i=0;
          break;
    }
  }
  setInterval(changecolor, 1000);
}());
```

Note that *setInterval* will run at about, not exactly, the specified interval. It will slowly lose time.

You can shorten the code by replacing the entire switch block with something like:

```
   var colours = ['red','green','blue']
   thesquare.style.backgroundColor = colours[i++ % colours.length];
```